# inso cli installation failure

Tags: npm, npm-install, insomnia

I have wsl2(ubunto) and using windows terminal I try to install insomnonia inso using the command "npm i -g insomnia-inso"

how ever I get error

```
    Could not run curl-config, please make sure libcurl dev package is installed.
Output: /bin/sh: 1: curl-config: not found

gyp: Call to 'node /usr/lib/node_modules/insomnia-inso/node_modules/node-libcurl/tools/curl-config.js --prefix' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.128-microsoft-standard
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/lib/node_modules/insomnia-inso/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding/node_libcurl.node" "--module_name=node_libcurl" "--module_path=/usr/lib/node_modules/insomnia-inso/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding" "--napi_version=6" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v79"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/insomnia-inso/node_modules/node-libcurl
gyp ERR! node -v v13.14.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/lib/node_modules/insomnia-inso/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding/node_libcurl.node --module_name=node_libcurl --module_path=/usr/lib/node_modules/insomnia-inso/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v79' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/insomnia-inso/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1026:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.128-microsoft-standard
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/insomnia-inso/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/insomnia-inso/node_modules/node-libcurl
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v13.14.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.15.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/lib/node_modules/insomnia-inso/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding/node_libcurl.node --module_name=node_libcurl --module_path=/usr/lib/node_modules/insomnia-inso/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v79' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules/insomnia-inso/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-libcurl@2.2.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-libcurl@2.2.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/limbido/.npm/_logs/2020-12-16T08_08_44_621Z-debug.log
```

I still have the same error after trying
"sudo npm i -g insomnia-inso --unsafe-perm"

Answer (score 1):

this command works for me

> sudo npm i -g insomnia-inso -unsafe-perm --allow-root